# issue in jest test

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am writing a jest for the component and and getting below error in the event:

```
ABS.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));

error i am getting :
TypeError: function xyz()
 {return mockConstructor.apply(this,arguments);} is not a valid component, 
 or does not extends LightningElement from "lwc". 
You probably forgot to add the extend clause on the class declaration.
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your post to provide a reproduction of this problem; the community cannot help you without seeing what you're actually doing. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more about our expectations.

Comment: Don't know if this is still an issue, but could you provide more of your code for your jest test, html and JS?